# Grails 2.4.4 Envers Auditing in a different schema and db migration plugin

Tags: grails, hibernate-envers, dbmigrate

I'm using Grails 2.4.4 with Hibernate Envers auditing. Envers is configured to use a different schema for _aud tables. Everything seems to work fine.

When first time dbm-gorm-diff is run, it correctly generates changelog for audit table creation. However, it does so everytime diff is run. It appears, that the db migration diff script does not take into account the target schema specified in the _aud classes.

Although I can manually delete the audit table creation portions of the changelog but the problem is when any audited table schema changes, I have to handwrite changes to the _aud tables.

Question is how do I ensure that dbmigration diffs with the target audit schema

Any solution or workaround is much appreciated.